# Specifying prefix to namespace JAXB

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, prefix

Facing issues with unmarshalling using JAXB. I need to use multiple namespaces.
The Java classes are generated for the XSDs provided by a third party. So I do not want to specify the namespace at XMLRootElement in the Java classes and do not want to manually change multiple classes.

The marshalling logic as below:

```
private <R extends BasicResponseType, T extends BasicRequestType> R doPost(T request, String requestname) throws Exception {
    if (jaxbContext == null)
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TokenRequest.class, TokenResponse.class,
                BasicResponseType.class, GeneralErrorResponse.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    logXML(marshaller, request);
    // POST to baseURL/requestname and show response
    HttpURLConnection conn = openConnection("/" + requestname);

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    marshaller.marshal(request, os);
    os.flush();
    // Normaler Output oder Error liefern, je nach HTTP Response
    InputStream is = null;
    boolean ok = true;
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        is = conn.getErrorStream();
        ok = false;
    } else {
        is = conn.getInputStream();
    }
    R response = (R) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
    is.close();
    conn.disconnect();
    logXML(marshaller, response);
    if (ok) {
        return response;
    } else {
        throw new Exception(getMessages((GeneralErrorResponse) response));
    }
}
```

The xmlelement class TokenRequest.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "TokenRequest")
public class TokenRequest
extends BasicInRequestType{ }
```

BasicInRequestType.java

```
package exp._3_0.api;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BasicInRequestType", propOrder = {
"software"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
TokenRequest.class    
})
public class BasicInRequestType
extends BasicRequestType {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected SoftwareType software;

/**
 * Gets the value of the software property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link SoftwareType }
 *     
 */
public SoftwareType getSoftware() {
    return software;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the software property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link SoftwareType }
 *     
 */
public void setSoftware(SoftwareType value) {
    this.software = value;
}}
```

BasicRequestType.java

```
package exp._3_0.api;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
propOrder = {
"header",
"user"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    BasicInRequestType.class
})
public class BasicRequestType {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected BasicHeaderType header;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected UserHeaderType user;
@XmlType(name = "BasicRequestType", namespace = "http://foo/1.0/common", 
/**
 * Gets the value of the header property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link BasicHeaderType }
 *     
 */
public BasicHeaderType getHeader() {
    return header;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the header property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link BasicHeaderType }
 *     
 */
public void setHeader(BasicHeaderType value) {
    this.header = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the user property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link UserHeaderType }
 *     
 */
public UserHeaderType getUser() {
    return user;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the user property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link UserHeaderType }
 *     
 */
public void setUser(UserHeaderType value) {
    this.user = value;
}}
```

XML Output :

```xml
<TokenRequest xmlns:common="http://foo/1.0/common" xmlns:ns4="http://foo/3.0/api" xmlns:base="http://foo/3.0/base">
    <common:header>
        <common:requestId></common:requestId>
        <common:timestamp></common:timestamp>
    </common:header>
    <common:user>
        <common:login></common:login>
        <common:passwordHash></common:passwordHash>
    </common:user>
    <software>
        <softwareId></softwareId>
        <softwareName></softwareName>
    </software>
</TokenRequest>
```

I have specifies the prefix in package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/3.0/api", prefix = ""),
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/3.0/base", prefix = "base"), 
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/1.0/common", prefix = "common") })
package exp._3_0.api;
```

The TokenRequest element actually refers to the namespace = "http://foo/3.0/api". In the xml output the TokenRequest does not have the any prefix which is correct but the xmlns is set to ns4 which is causing the below error.

> Request body contains on line: [1] and column: [182] error:
> [unexpected element (uri:"", local:"TokenRequest"). Expected elements
> are <{http://foo/3.0/api}TokenRequest>]

Even after specifying the prefix = "" for namespace "http://foo/3.0/api" in package-info, in the output its still appending as ns4. Please help how to fix remove the ns4.

Comment: Please explicitly set the namespace in: `@XmlRootElement(name = "TokenRequest", namespace="http://foo/3.0/api")
public class TokenRequest ...` (?) (and parents!?)

Comment: Alternatively you should add `namespace="http://foo/3.0/api"` to your `@XmlSchema` annotation. In the current form `TokenRequest`'s namespace in `""` (i.e. no namespace).

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for the suggestion. But as mentioned before i do not want to manually add the namespace to XMLRootElement as there many classes which i will need to modify. I am looking for a generic solution for all the classes. Is there any other way?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have already defined the namespace to "" in the package-infor

Comment: @JuhiVhadadi: can you edit the question and add the modified `package-info.java`? All we can see is `@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/3.0/api", prefix = "")`, which only sets the preferred prefix for `http://foo/3.0/api`. There is no `namespace="..."` attribute (which sets the namespace for the whole package).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz - Below is the details of package-info.java `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/3.0/api", prefix = ""),
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/3.0/base", prefix = "base"), 
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/1.0/common", prefix = "common") })
package exp._3_0.api;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As remarked in the comments, your `@XmlSchema` lacks a `namespace` attribute, therefore all `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlType` are considered to be without a namespace, unless **explicitly** qualified. Your `java-package.info` should look like this:

```java
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, namespace = "http://foo/3.0/api", xmlns = {
      @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/3.0/api", prefix = ""),
      @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/3.0/base", prefix = "base"),
      @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://foo/1.0/common", prefix = "common")})
package exp._3_0.api;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

The `@XmlNs` annotation **does not** specify the default namespace used in the Java package. They only provide a **suggestion** to the JAXB implementation on what prefixes to assign to those namespaces. In your example the tags `<TokenRequest>`, `<software>`, `<softwareId>` and `<softwareName>` do not belong to any namespace, therefore JAXB uses an empty prefix for these elements and must use another prefix (`ns4`) for the elements in the `http://foo/3.0/api` namespace (there aren't any).